# Jhipster deploy frontend separate from backend

Tags: jhipster

Hi I want to deploy the jhipster frontend separated , can I do it ? or the correct way is to put it back in the same project with the backend.I can't find info on how to deploy it after been separated

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it separately, you just need a web server to serve your frontend bundle and if you want to avoid CORS issues you should also configure it as a reverse proxy to your backend.

The web server could also be a CDN.

The reason why you don't find any JHipster doc on this is that it's not specific to JHipster.

Comment: Ok I tried npm's Like: npm run-script build , but doesn't work to build from sources do you have any suggestion , thanks

Comment: This does not seem to be related to your initial question about deployment. Please open a new question with more details about the error and consider accepting this answer.